# Create a timeout for a set of tasks assigned to a threadpool java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Hi I am having a problem regarding timing out tasks assigned to a thread pool java.

In detail:

1. I have implemented an API which runs some queries in parallel and returns the response.
2. There is a fixed thread pool created via `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(40)`. Whenever someone calls this API, a set of 10 tasks are schedules on this thread pool. These tasks internally execute a set of queries on Mysql.
3. I have to return the response for the API with an SLA of 6-7 sec. So I have to create a timeout for all the 10 tasks that were scheduled on the thread pool. I know how to timeout a single task (It throws an interrupted exception although the thread becomes free only if it is completed once it is started).
4. I also don't want to overload the thread pool. So I have created a timeout of 60 sec for all the queries that run via the tasks assigned to this thread pool. So the threads become free to take up another task within a minute.

Question:

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

```
@Component
public class MyHandler {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        /*
        * Naming thread pool to identify threads in the thread dump
        * */

        ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
            .setNameFormat("my-thread-%d").build();

        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool("40", threadFactory);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    public void update() {
        List<Future<Boolean>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        results.add(executorService.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                executeQuery();
                return true;
            }
        }));

        /*
        * 9 more such tasks
        */


         for (Future<Boolean> result : results) {
            try {
                result.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Failed with unknown error", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`executeQuery()` has a timeout scheduled for 60 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ExecutorService.invokeAll()` to run a collection of tasks with a timeout. After the method finishes (finished work or timed-out) you will have to check all the futures to see if they were canceled (because of the timeout) or finished. If they are finished you will have to check that they finished because the work was done, not because of an  exception (when you call `Future.get`).

The code may look like this:

```
    final ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    final List<Future<Double>> futures = service.invokeAll(tasks, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    final List<CallableTask> tasks = Arrays.asList(new CallableTask(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
            new CallableTask(1, TimeUnit.HOURS), new CallableTask(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
            new CallableTask(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

    for (Future<Double> result : futures) {
        if (!result.isCancelled())  {
            try {
                System.out.println("Result: " + result.get());
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // Task wasn't completed because of exception, may be required to handle this case
            }
        }
    }
```

In my case, CallableTask is a Callable implementation and it's used to make the code more simple since all the tasks submitted are the same. You can use the same approach to simplify your code.

I've added a sample of how the CallableTask looks like:

```
    public class CallableTask implements Callable<Double> {

    private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final int timeout;
    private final TimeUnit timeUnit;
    private final int taskNumber = count.incrementAndGet();

    public CallableTask(int timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        this.timeout = timeout;
        this.timeUnit = timeUnit;
    }

    @Override
    public Double call() {
        System.out.println("Starting task " + taskNumber);
        try {
            timeUnit.sleep(timeout);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Task interrupted: " + taskNumber);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("Ending task " + taskNumber);
        return Math.random();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ExecutorSerive.invokeAll(List<Callable<T>> tasks, long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit)` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-). Take a look at following code sample:

```
package com.github.wololock;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

final class ExecutorsServiceInvokeAnyExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        final List<Callable<String>> tasks = Arrays.asList(
                () -> {
                    debug("This task runs for 1 second");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    debug("Task completed!");
                    return "1";
                },
                () -> {
                    debug("This task runs for 2 seconds");
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    debug("Task completed!");
                    return "2";
                },
                () -> {
                    debug("This task runs for 3 seconds");
                    Thread.sleep(2999);
                    debug("Task completed!");
                    return "3";
                },
                () -> {
                    debug("This task runs for 4 seconds");
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                    debug("Task completed!");
                    return "4";
                },
                () -> {
                    debug("This task runs for 5 seconds");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    debug("Task completed!");
                    return "5";
                }
        );

        try {
            final List<Future<String>> result = executor.invokeAll(tasks, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (result.stream().anyMatch(Future::isCancelled)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("All tasks were not completed...");
            }
        } finally {
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }

    private static void debug(String msg) {
        System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] " + msg);
    }
}
```

We are triggering `invokeAll` with 5 tasks, where the fastest one takes 1 second to complete and the slowest one needs 5 seconds to complete. Invocation timeout is set to 3 seconds and only 3 tasks will complete in that time. In this example I throw a `RuntimeException` if not all tasks are completed - it depends on your business case what you will do if this situation occurs. Here is exemplary output of running this example:

```
[pool-1-thread-2] This task runs for 2 seconds
[pool-1-thread-1] This task runs for 1 second
[pool-1-thread-4] This task runs for 4 seconds
[pool-1-thread-3] This task runs for 3 seconds
[pool-1-thread-5] This task runs for 5 seconds
[pool-1-thread-1] Task completed!
[pool-1-thread-2] Task completed!
[pool-1-thread-3] Task completed!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: All tasks were not completed...
```

If I give 6 seconds timeout, then everything completes correctly and there is no exception thrown:

```
[pool-1-thread-1] This task runs for 1 second
[pool-1-thread-5] This task runs for 5 seconds
[pool-1-thread-4] This task runs for 4 seconds
[pool-1-thread-2] This task runs for 2 seconds
[pool-1-thread-3] This task runs for 3 seconds
[pool-1-thread-1] Task completed!
[pool-1-thread-2] Task completed!
[pool-1-thread-3] Task completed!
[pool-1-thread-4] Task completed!
[pool-1-thread-5] Task completed!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### EDIT: Task timeout != Database server timeout

There is one more thing you should consider very closely. As you mentioned in the question, your task is going to execute MySQL query. Keep in mind that if your task terminates it doesn't mean that query execution was stopped - it only means that server didn't respond in those 5-6 seconds, but most probably query is still being executed. In this case you may run into false assumption that task was not completed while it took more time, but eventually MySQL server query was executed, but there is no result returned to your task. Another thing is that in this case you lost control over committing transaction to the database, which might be crucial in your case. I hope it will help you in better understanding what is the best solution to your problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about db server timeout. In my case, I don't care if the query is still running on the server as I have already sent the API response. But you are correct at the point where the server might still be running the query. If that's the case, the connection which is being used to serve the query will not be free. The app might get starved of db connections from the pool when needed. I might have to address that problem as well probably. Since the other answer is also the same and was answered before this, I will have to accept the other one. Sorry!

Comment: No probs, helping you in solving your problem matters the most :)